# jupyter notebook showing None type values but IDLE doesn't

Tags: python, nltk, jupyter-notebook, python-idle

```
max_sim = -1.0
best_pair = None, None
for synset_1 in synsets_1:
    for synset_2 in synsets_2:
        sim = wn.path_similarity(synset_1, synset_2)
        print (sim)
        if sim > max_sim:
            max_sim = sim
            best_pair = synset_1, synset_2
```

The code is cosine similarity by using of nltk packages , i am able to execute and see the output in the IDLE. But in the jupyter notebook 'sim' is showing some 'None' values

Comment: Please provide output of IDLE and jupyter notebook 'sim'.

Comment: https://github.com/mlwmlw/php-cosine-similarity  the idle output of 'sim' is continuously varying variable with in range of 0-1 , can you please debug and let me know